# Script tag Hidden Scrapping with python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the price of a product from this url and I'm using BeautifulSoap version 4

`url = https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-722339/%DA%A9%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D9%85%D8%BA%D8%A7%D8%B2%D9%87-%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%AF%DA%A9%D8%B4%DB%8C-%D8%A7%D8%AB%D8%B1-%DA%98%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%AA%D9%88%D9%84%DB%8C/`

but since the price is in a script tag I can't find it when I'm using bs4
after a certain level it's like empty!

This is my code:
`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-722339/%DA%A9%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D9%85%D8%BA%D8%A7%D8%B2%D9%87-%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%AF%DA%A9%D8%B4%DB%8C-%D8%A7%D8%AB%D8%B1-%DA%98%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%AA%D9%88%D9%84%DB%8C/"

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
price = soup.find('body').find('div', id='__next')
print(price)
```

`

[[target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTwzA.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdrtM.png)

Comment: the links above this comment are some pictures

Comment: For this case you have to crawl it using WebDriver, you can use selenium in this case where you will wait for javascript to be loaded and then get the price.